The number of functions $f : \{1, . . 100\} \to \{1, . . . , 100\}$ such that $f(x) \neq x,$ and $f(f(x)) = x$ for all $x$
I tried looking at the condition $f(f(x))=x.$ Which means $f$ is bijective. So it must be either strictly increasing or decreasing, but I feel this is severely under counting. Also the condition $f(x)\neq x$ isn't making sense to me.

how to ask a good question here and mathjax tutorial - you need to take care these two things.

Try a permuatation of the form $(ab)(cd) \cdots$ ... How many of these are there ?

The strictly increasing or decreasing only applies to continuous bijections.  Without continuity you can have a bijection that is neither.  A simple example is from ${1,2,3}$ with $f(1)=1, f(2)=3, f(3)=2$

Is your requirement $f(x) \neq x$ that the function not be the identity or that for no $x$ is $f(x)=x$?  Those are very different.  Certainly the identity function satisfies $f(f(x))=f(x)=x$

@RossMillikan yes the inequality is for all x

it's the multinomial coefficient of 100 items split into 50 pairs.

$~f(f(x)) = x,~$ will be true if and only if the function $~f~$ is its own inverse.  This means that if $~f(x) = y,~$ then you must have that [1] $~x \neq y,~$ and [2] $~f(y) = x.$

Functions $f$ for which $f(f(x))=x$ for all $x$ are known as involutions. So, the problem is essentially asking for the number of involutions on ${1, ..., 100}$ with no fixed points.

I'll call the functions $f:\{0,...,100\}\to \{0,...,100\}$ that satisfy your condition "good functions". Notice that you can construct a good function as follows:

Divide the set $\{0,...,100\}$ into $50$ disjoint doubletons $\{a_1,b_1\},...,\{a_{50},b_{50}\}$ (I'll call such a subdivision a "good subdivision". The order of the doubletons doesn't matter.).
Define $f(a_i)=b_i$ (and consequently $a_i=f(b_i)$).

We constructed a method to associate to each good subdivision a good function. You can do also the opposite!
Given a good function $f$, if you remove the repeating doubletons from $$\{1,f(1)\},...,\{100,f(100)\}$$ you get a good subdivision.
We've just created a bijection between good functions and good subdivisions, so we need only to count good subdivisions.
To construct a good subdivision you can choose choose a permutation of $\{1 ... 100\}$. For example:
$$2  \ \ \ 57 \ \ \ 91 \ \ \ 7  \ \ \ 9  \ \ 13 \ \ \ ...$$
and you can couple the elements like this:
$$2  \ \ \ 57 \ \ | \ \ 91 \ \ \ 7  \ \ | \  \ 9  \ \ 13 \ \ | \ ...$$
But this procedure doesn't give you $100!$ good subdivisions, because different permutations can give the same subdivisions. This happens for two reasons:

You can simply swap the elements of a couple like this:
$$2  \ \ \ 57 \ \ |\ \ \color{red}{ 7 \ \ \ 91  } \ \ | \  \ 9  \ \ 13 \ \ | \ ...$$
since there are $50$ couples, you can do this in $2^{50}$ ways.

You can permute the couples themselves:
$$\color{red}{ 91 \ \ \ 7  } \ \ |\ \ \color{red}{ 2 \ \ \ 57  } \ \ | \  \ 9  \ \ 13 \ \ | \ ...$$
Here we switched the first couple with the second. Clearly there are $50!$ ways of permuting the couples.


Accounting for these two kinds of overcounting we get that the answer is
$$\frac{100!}{2^{50}\cdot 50!}$$

Indeed, $f$ must be bijective, but it need not be monotonic (that would be the case if $f$ was also assumed continuous). Since $f(f(x)) = x$, then $f(x) = y$ implies $f(y) = x$. All permutations of the type $(ab), (ab)(cd)$ etc. satisfy this condition. But we also need $f(x) \neq x$, hence we cannot have any single element cycles. All permutations in $S_{100}$ that are composed of $50$ two cycles satisfy both of these conditions.  Let $D$ be the set of such permutations.
We claim that the elements of $D$ are the only functions satisfying the two conditions. This is easy to check: just let $E$ be the set of solutions, and show that $D = E$.
Now what is left is to count the number of elements of $D$. Can you proceed from here?

It does look like a particular case of  the number of permutations of $\{1, \ldots, n\}$ of a given cycle type (found by Cauchy).
